# Is there any way to call/ execute Oracle Function via Postgres?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, function-call, oracle-fdw

I have a requirement to migrate Oracle DB to Postgres, in which I am able to do so.
By using FDW, I am able to access Oracle data at Postgres.
Now there is a requirement to call/execute a function of Oracle via Postgres.

Is there any way to do so?

I have Found this link, for the same:
https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/issues/187

Can any one provide me with a sample or an example?

Regards,

Comment: You could probably do this fairly easily by wrapping the function call in a [`plpythonu`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) or [`plperlu`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) function. Alternatively, you could write some script which takes its arguments from stdin and invoke it via [`COPY TO PROGRAM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). You'll need superuser permissions to do any of these things. And unlike Laurenz's FDW approach, you lose transaction integrity on the Oracle side. But no changes required to Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use this simple Oracle function for test purposes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION double(n NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
   RETURN n * 2;
END;
/
```

Then an Oracle table that we can use with oracle_fdw:

```
CREATE TABLE call_double(inp NUMBER, outp NUMBER);

INSERT INTO call_double VALUES (1, 1);

COMMIT;
```

Now we create a `BEFORE` trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER double_trig BEFORE UPDATE ON call_double FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.outp := double(:NEW.inp);
END;
/
```

Now we can create and use a foreign table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE call_double(
   inp numeric OPTIONS (key 'true'),
   outp numeric)
SERVER oracle OPTIONS (table 'CALL_DOUBLE');

UPDATE call_double SET inp = 12 RETURNING outp;

┌──────┐
│ outp │
├──────┤
│   24 │
└──────┘
(1 row)
```

Not exactly pretty, but it does the trick.